# panic: dial tcp: lookup bookstoreDB on 172.22.64.1:53: no such host

Tags: docker, go, networking, go-gorm

First post here!
Trying to connect to a mysql server from docker using golang,gin, and gorm but I'm having issues connecting to the server through gorm.

Here is the error I am getting :

`panic: dial tcp: lookup bookstoreDB on 172.22.64.1:53: no such host`

Here is how I am trying to initiate the connection through gorm:

```
func Connect() {
    d, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "docker:password@tcp(bookstoreDB)/bookstore")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db = d
}
```

Here's what my docker-compose.yml file looks like:

```
version: "3.8"

services: 
  mysql_server:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: bookstoreDB
    environment: 
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=bookstore
      - MYSQL_USER=docker
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Here is what appears when I run the "docker-compose ps" command:

```
   Name                 Command             State                 Ports
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bookstoreDB   docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld   Up      0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
```

Here is a screenshot of my project structure :

[bookstore project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9nsf.png)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Where/how do you run the go application? That service name is only resolvable from within the same docker-compose.

Comment: @zerkms I'm running the go application from my main.go that is nested into my project with "go run main.go". I will add a screenshot of my current project directory structure.

Comment: But do you run it from within a container that is a part of the same docker-compose?

Comment: If you are not running your project in a container that's part of the docker-compose you will NOT be able to directly point your system to the container's IP.  Instead, you would point your application running on the host machine that runs the container to `127.0.0.1:3306` instead of the Docker container IP.  The Docker container IP is only reachable from within the docker network segment that docker-compose launches for the composed environment.

Comment: Thank you zerkms and Thomas Ward! This clarifies everything. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are trying to connect to a hostname that is totally unknown out of the docker-compose cluster.

```
d, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "docker:password@tcp(bookstoreDB)/bookstore")
```

`bookstoreDB` is totally unknown here. The idea of mapping the ports (as you are doing with mySql's one :

```
   Name                 Command             State                 Ports
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bookstoreDB   docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld   Up      0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
```

Is to use that mapping as connection to the database (not the container's intra host name).

Change your code so you connect to your localhost:3306 instead. This is pseudocode as don't understand the language:

```
d, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "<docker:password@tcp(localhost)/bookstore>")
```

Comment: Thank you @aran, following your suggestion, it now seems that the connection is being found!

Comment: @luigi if it helped, could you mark it as valid : ) (thats helps me and you!)

Comment: thanks @luigi! Did it as well with you : )